# Huge memory consumption while selecting a postgresql array element combined with unnest

Tags: postgresql

When I create a temporary table in Postgresql 9.5 with one row containing a not very small int array

```
select array_agg(t.i) ids into temp table tmp1 from (select generate_series(1,100000) i) t;
```

this following query uses tens of gigabytes of memory (and lots of time):

```
select ids[1] id_to, unnest(ids) id_from into temp table tmp2 from tmp1;
```

I did not expect this and would like to understand why selecting an array element together with an unnest requires so much resources. Without selecting ids[1] everything goes fine.

As a workaround I'm using this, which is memory-efficient and fast:

```
select array_agg(t.i) ids into temp table tmp1 from (select generate_series(1,80000) i) t;
alter table tmp1 add column id1 int;
update tmp1 set id1 = ids[1];
select id1 id_to, unnest(ids) id_from into temp table tmp2 from tmp1;
```

Comment: provide query analyze.

Comment: explain analyze select ids[1] id_to, unnest(ids) id_from into temp table tmp2 from tmp1;

`Seq Scan on tmp1  (cost=0.00..674.83 rows=131000 width=32) (actual time=0.407..11027.342 rows=100000 loops=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your memory-consuming query is presumably going to instantiate your big array once for every row in `unnest(ids)` and then extract the first element from it. I'm not sure what else it could do.

I suppose there could be an optimization that notices this is a constant, but that's not going to generally be true so it's not the sort of thing you would count on.

You could alternatively do something like this:

```
WITH first AS (SELECT ids[1] AS elem1 FROM tmp1) 
SELECT elem1, unnest(ids) FROM tmp1, first;
```

I'm curious as to your use-case for this though. In general, if you want to access individual elements of an array you probably wanted a separate table and a join.

Comment: Thanks, your CTE is of course more elegant as it avoids a schema change. Instantiating an array of size 100000 should in my view however only require memory in the MB range, not Gigabytes. - As for my use case: The rows in tmp1 are equivalence classes and I want to select just one representative and maps the old ids to the new one (representative).

Comment: You aren't instantiating one array, you are instantiating one array *for every row* in your result-set. For your use-case I'm not sure why you are bothering with the arrays at all.